# create a function that returns a new instance of a class - Processing

Tags: java, function, class, return, processing

How do I return a new instance of a class using a function and the function wouldn't take any parameter. I'm using Processing. If someone can help me out. That would be awesome if there is a code example.
Thank you

Comment: function x() {`return new ClassName();`} ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, by using generics.

```
public <T> T getObjectFromMethod(Class<T> object) {
    try {
        return object.newInstance();
    } catch() { }
}
```